# Refresh Oauth2 scope while using decorator in App Engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, python-decorators

I'm using OAuth2Decorator in order to ensure that the required credentials are present before the get() method of RequestHandler is invoked. This flow is working fine.

Now, as I needed to get additional scopes, I just added that to the list of scopes in OAuth2Decorator. However, this doesn't trigger any authentication flow. Due to this, the newly added scopes are not available in the get() method.

At this point, when calling external API that requires the added scopes, I get an error that I've insufficient permissions.

One working solution I found was to remove permissions for my application manually. However, I cannot expect that my users will do the same in order to access the website.

https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1

The other alternative is to switch to a new client id, so that the authentication flow is triggered automatically.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you consider this better but you can do it programmably. Wrap a call in a try except with your except being:

```
except HttpError:
    creds = decorator.get_credentials()
    creds.revoke(decorator.http())
    self.redirect("/")
```

It will cause the user to be removed then redirected back to auth. Only gave it a quick test so you may need to tweek a bit.